# after-action-before-render kind of interceptor (Play 1.x)

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I know of the existence of `@Before` and `@After`, but `@After` happens to execute after the rendering of the template

Almost all my controllers extends a specific class of mine, and I want to, unobtrusively, be able to execute some code in my super class that checks for some conditions and sets some flash/renderArgs **after** the execution of the code in the subclass, but **before** the rendering is done

any simple way to achieve this?

edit: here's a snippet of the code

```
class MyController extends Controller {
   @After
   static void checkStage() {
      if (xyz) {
         flash.put("stage", "bla");
      }
   }
}
```

my controllers all extend `MyController` but since the `checkStage` code is called **AFTER** the rendering is done, the `stage` flash attribute will be rendered the **next** time a page is rendered

Actually, I would want to use `flash.now` instead of `flash.put`, but because the code `@After` code is executed after the rendering, it never shows up

Comment: Just an idea for a quick solution for this: Why don't you make a subclass of `Controller` where you override the `render()` method with _stuff you want to do_ + a call to `Controller`'s `render()`, and then make your controllers inherit `YourFancyController` instead of `Controller`?

Comment: that wouldn't work with redirects, AFAIK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you want simplest:  just insert the check code before you call render().  That is the most simple approach!

If you want something more complex, you could make a Plugin that overrides `loadTemplate` https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/master/framework/src/play/PlayPlugin.java#L157 and wraps the Template returned with your extra code.  The other part of this you need to look at is the template loader: https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/master/framework/src/play/templates/TemplateLoader.java#L58  - Seems awfully convoluted, but could work.

Maybe you should explain why you are trying to do this pre-render code - there could be a better approach.

---

Edit:  Ok, I see what you are trying to do.  Yes, once the request is sent, you cannot modify cookies (aka flash).  I'd suggest you avoid using cookies to maintain state between transactions - each variable adds to the HTTP transaction and is sent on every request.

Instead, I suggest you use Cache.set(Session.getId(), map) and put all the state values in the Map.  Then I think you can save them during an @After

Example here; http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.5/controllers#session

Comment: the code is executed in a superclass, I added some code and clarifications of what I want to do

Comment: hmm, just had a thought - you could do this in the template itself.  presumably your templates extend a base template (eg, main.html in the default play project)?  you could invoke your extra logic inside the template.

Comment: I did try a WHOLE lot of stuff, but the internal "magic" of play makes it very difficult to mess with the Controllers (static methods, local variable names resolution, etc, etc)... I think I'll do the quick & dirty "code in the template" solution, at least for now

Comment: Yeah, I think that'll be the best you can do.  Please see the final edit I made, I think quite possibly you should not be using flash/session (aka cookies) for managing state.

Comment: I'm not managing state, just adding (via flash) some notifications to the user

Comment: Maybe you could use `Cache.get(key,ObjectType.class)` instead http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.5/cheatsheet/controllers

Answer (score 0):

DISCLAIMER: it's been a while since I've used Play 1.x, take it with a grain of salt

If I understand you want to do something like:

```
public static void myMethod() {
   // myMethod code here

   // some common code here

   renderTemplate("myTemplate.html", id, client);
}
```

You should be able to extract this common part onto your parent controller to a method like:

```
public static void renderMyTemplate(String template, Object... params){
   // some common code here
   renderTemplate(template, params);
}
```

and replace your calls to `render`by calls to this method. This should tackle your issue.

Comment: the interceptor code is executed in a superclass, I added some code and clarifications of what I want to do

Comment: @Shaga I don't understand your question. The idea would be to eliminate the `@After` and instead create that helper method in the superclass, adding the common code and using `renderTemplate`to render the correct template for your controller requests

Comment: what I was looking for is a method that doesn't require me to change  the sub-controllers, something in the lines of Before and After, but I think that doesn't exist

Comment: @Shaga unfortunately I think there's no alternative, unless you hack the framework by creating new annotations that run when you want